# Process state transition from READY to TERMINATED

Tags: process, operating-system

This is a theoretical operating systems question:
In which occasions can a process go from the READY state directly to the TERMINATED state without passing through RUNNING?

Is this just happening when the process is killed while being in READY state?

Comment: What makes you think there is a single answer to this question?

Comment: I did not assume a single answer. Why there cannot be multiple answers?

Comment: @Thorben there can be multiple answers, which is why your question is gonna get closed.

Comment: Single answer is a better question for [so]. Please see [ask]. Your question could reasonably elicit most of the chapter on [process states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state) from an operating systems textbook.

Comment: Sure, why not?  It's actually easier if all the threads of the process are not running or, if the process is requesting its own termination, if only the thread requesting the terminatiion is running.

Comment: @John Saunders: The article you mentioned does not state anything about how many valid answers there could/should be. And by the way the most questions have a lot of possible answers. Furthermore, I have already read the Wikipedia article you linked before and as you could have seen, it does not link from the READY to the TERMINATED state. But I know from a lecture that there must be some cases when this happens.

Comment: @Martin James: I think when at least one thread of a process is running, the whole process is in the RUNNING state.

Comment: If you heard it in a lecture, then you should ask the lecturer. If the lecture had been about the behavior of a particular version of a particular OS, then there would be a particular answer. Otherwise, the lecture was about generalities, and would only possibly have a general answer which has little to do with the real world.

Comment: @Thorben OK, with you definition of 'RUNNING' and 'READY', then you are asking about and out-of-process termination where none of the threads of the target process are running on a core.  That's very easy for the OS since it does not need to stop any threads running on cores.  It can just whip the thread control block pointers out from whatever ready/synchro/IO container they are currently stuck in and then start releasing whatever resources the process had acquired during its run.  There is no need to run any of the target process threads upon termination - why would it do such a crazy thing?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what I'm wondering. I just saw on my slides that there is a connection, but without an explanation. But I will try to ask the responsible, who wasn't available during the weekend, about it and then post the response.

Answer (score 0):

Let there is a parent process which have 3 child process. If parent process is  processing and after some time, it abort then the child process will gone from ready to terminated state.

Comment: Why are the child processes in READY state? 
Normally they should be in RUNNING state after creation unless they don't wait for signals or something else.